# Not mapping JSON right in loops swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, mapping

This is in Swift 3

I am receiving an array of "segments" as JSON.
I am trying to map my data in a array of an object.

It seems that I am doing it wrong. I am getting the same amount in "duration" in every element of the array, which it's not. 
I am not sure if it is the way I am running it through a loop, or what the problem is. Can anyone plz help?

Thanks a lot!

```
if let segmentsArray = resultData["Segments"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
  var segments = [Segment]()
  for segment in segmentsArray {
    if let duration = segment["Duration"] as? NSInteger {
      if let key = segment["Key"] as? String {
        if let legIndexes = segment["LegIndexes"] as? NSArray {
          if let stops = segment["Stops"] as? NSInteger {
            let thisSegment = Segment.init(duration: duration, key: key, legIndexes: legIndexes as! [NSInteger], stops:stops)
            segments.append(thisSegment)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does `segmentsArray` look like (print it)? What durations are you getting? Some debugging info would be helpful.

Comment: Your code works for me. Could you provide some sample JSON data, and the generated `segments` array?